# Android, extract javascript variable from webview using javascript interface

Tags: javascript, android

How can I extract this variable bellow from a website to my android code?
I guess it should work using javascript interface but how do I get it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Ids = "[4161, 104, 121, 202, 1462]";
</script>
```

And I can't change the code on the website to a method that returns the value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `javascript:` scheme in a webview.loadurl call. It will execute the javascript in the webview page.

From there you can make it call a function in your javascript interface.

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:Android.getIds(Ids);");
```

Android being the name space used to declare your javascript interface.

```
//Add the javascript interface to your web view
this.addJavascriptInterface(new CustomJavaScriptInterface(webViewContext), "Android");
```

Beware that javascriptinterface only work with primitive types. So you actually can't pass directly an array. Just use the javascript scheme to loop through your array. I see it is not really an array so you should be fine with just :

```
public class CustomJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    CustomJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    

    /** retrieve the ids */
    public void getIds(final String myIds) {
        
        //Do somethings with the Ids
    }
    
}
```

Comment: this.addJavaScripInterface(...)
where I have to call this ?

Comment: got called. with webview :)