# Read variable inside <script> tag inside Android WebView

Tags: javascript, php, android, android-webview

I'm loading a php page inside an Android WebView (is a third part page, so i can't modify it), and the result is something like:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        //something in head 
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        // a script for load content
        </script>
        // other stuffs

       <script> var varToRead=100;</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And i need to read value of varToRead for doing some stuff inside my app.
How can i access it?

Comment: You can do this with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991515/android-extract-javascript-variable-from-webview-using-javascript-interface

Answer (score 0):

you could use a Javascriptinterface like it's described here: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)